# how to make dependency injection in spring java

Tags: java, spring

i have code bellow, i code without dependency injection,
i still dont get point what is advantage using dependency injection

interface class

```
@Component
public interface TextWriter {
    public String WriteText(String s);
}
```

class one

```
public class YonoWriter implements TextWriter{
    @Override
    public String WriteText(String s) {
        return s + " 1 ";
    }
}
```

class two

```
public class Yono2Writer {
    TextWriter text;
    Yono2Writer(){
        text = new YonoWriter();
    }
    public String hello(String s){
        return this.text.WriteText(" 2 ") + s;
    }
}
```

final class

```
@RestController
public class Yono3Writer {
    Yono2Writer text;
    Yono3Writer(){
        text = new Yono2Writer();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public  String hello2(){
        return this.text.hello("3");
    }
}
```

and the result is 2 1 3 and what is expected is 123 and how to implement dependency injection there ?

Comment: To get the result you're expecting, change `YonoWriter#WriteText` method body from `return s + " 1 ";` to `return "1" + s;` and remove spaces around `" 2 "` in `Yono2Writer#hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn what more about dependency injection (DI) check [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-introduction)

The summary of DI or IoC (inversion of control) is that the component defines the dependency and then the spring context injects a proper instance of the dependency, hence inversion of control. So instead of:

```
@RestController
public class Yono3Writer {
    Yono2Writer text; // <- 1. component defines the dependency
    Yono3Writer(){
        text = new Yono2Writer(); // <- 2. component creates the dependency by itself as part of constructing the component
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public  String hello2(){
        return this.text.hello("3");
    }
}
```

You get this:

```
@RestController
public class Yono3Writer {
    Yono2Writer text; // <- 1. component defines the dependency

    Yono3Writer(Yono2Writer yono2Writer){
        this.text = yono2Writer; // <- 2. a spring managed bean is injected using the constructor as part of constructing the component
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public  String hello2(){
        return this.text.hello("3");
    }
}
```

provided that you configured a bean of type `Yono2Writer`, one way to do that:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public Yono2Writer yono2Writer() {
        return new Yono2Writer();
    }

}
```

This is really helpful when you have a bunch of these dependencies for your component that are not all straight forward to implement unlike `new Yono2Writer()`